# How can I cast an integer to an id in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

My code is something like this:

```
[request setPostValue:employee.empId forKey:@"empId"];
```

where employee is a "POCO" object that has a property empId which is int, but the method is waiting an identifier.

I've tried already sending setPostValue:&employee.empId and setPostValue:[employee.empId] but still getting errors.

Can I get the (id) in any way? or must I create another object from the property?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yeah, you need to create another object from the integer before you can hand it off to a method that’s expecting an `id`.

```
[request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:employee.empId] forKey:@"empId"];
```

Alternatively, with more recent versions of the SDK (post-iOS 6, I think?), you can use Objective-C’s new boxing literals:

```
[request setPostValue:@(employee.empId) forKey:@"empId"];
```

Comment: wow that was fast, thanks I'm learning, not so easy to step down from C# :(

Answer (score 6):

```
[request setPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:employee.empId] forKey:@"empId"];
```